# How can I set background color/image specific tab at QTabWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtabbar, qtstylesheets

After the long visitor status, finally, this is my first post. 
I create tabs dynamically in my TabWidget(from config). Like;
-it is python code, pyqt, answers can be coded c++, dosn’t matter for me :) –

```
baseWidget = QWidget()
//fill baseWidget with other widgets
window.tabWidget.addTab(baseWidget, _fromUtf8(""))
window.tabWidget.setTabText(window.tabWidget.indexOf(baseWidget), ...)
```

Then, style via qss, like;

```
QTabBar::tab {}
QTabBar::tab:selected {}
QTabBar::tab:!selected {}
QTabBar::tab:last {}
QTabBar::tab:first:!selected {}
QTabBar::tab:!selected:hover {}
```

At this point everything is OK. But, i want to colorize my tabs individually.

How can i achieve this?
If it is possible, how can set objectName for a tab?

All post will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Changing base object name won't help, all you are going to do with base object's stylesheet is to change the content background of that panel.

I did a lot of research and tested a few things regarding your problem and it seems like the only solution is to re-implement the `QTabWidget` paint event.

I tried somethings that I haven't read anywhere else and it gave some weird results, this approach should've worked. If you want to study it and see for yourself:

```
tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
tabWidget->tabBar()->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");

tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
tabWidget->tabBar()->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;");
```